# Error on connection to PPTP VPN on aws - The VPN connection between your computer and the VPN server could not be completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, pptp

I have an EC2 (t2.micro) on aws as a test server and I am trying to create a simple PPTP VPN server with internet connection.
I followed some tutorials and did as follow:

1. Add roles and feature (Remote Access)
2. Add a user in computer management with 'Allow access' option enabled.
3. Enabled and configured 'Routing and Remote Access' security MS-CHAP v2, and enabled IPv4 forwarding with range between 192.168.10.10-192.168.10.19
4. In 'Routing and Remote Access' Under IPv4-NAT created public Ethernet interface with NAT enabled.
5. In the server allow access for port 1723 (TCP Inbound rule).
6. On amazon console created allow access TCP inbound rule for port 1723.

Now when I try to connect to my server from my PC using PPTP connection (with MS-CHAP v2 and optional encryption) it shows the following error after a while:
[image]

AM I missing a step or something configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling on it for few days I found out that I needed to add GRE (47) as inbound rule in AWS console (security group) for the instance as well.

[image: Security group]